# How to call self class method inside the same model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, class-method

I'm trying to do validation skipping as someone described in [this post](http://gistflow.com/posts/749-canceling-validations-in-activerecord). Whole process of canceling is working for me, but I've trouble with this syntax:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # [...]
    remove_email_uniq_validation

    def self.remove_email_uniq_validation
        # do something
    end
    # [...]
end
```

Got:

```
[...] gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `remove_email_uniq_validation' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong regarding to example from Gistflow and what's a correct way to call methods like this directly in model class?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method doesn't exist at the point you're trying to call it. Move the def in front of the call and it will work.

Comment: omg, I refused this solution at the beginning. I said: "It's not C, order should not matter". Anyway, it works. Do you have any idea why author of "canceling validation" on Gistflow used code like this? Simple mistake or other solution?

Comment: Ruby is an interpreted language; when you say `class X` it creates a new class X and runs the following lines in the context of the newly opened class, with `self` set to `X`. So `remove_email_uniq_validation` on the next line is just a regular, ordinary method call on the object called `X`, meaning there must be a method called `remove_email_uniq_validation` on it (or on an ancestor of it, or a module it includes, then it tries `method_missing` etc.) The original author made a mistake, as you could see yourself when trying to run his code.

Comment: You can immediately spot the mistake when you rephrase the code like this: `X = Class.new; X.remove_email_uniq_validation; X.define_singleton_method(:remove_email_uniq_validation) { ... }`